# Repeat the Group Footer on each page

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

**Does anyone knows how to repeat the Group Footer on each page. In Crystal report desing, only option is available to repeat the Group header**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know group footer will be printed only once after printing all the records.
I found a workaround at http://scn.sap.com/thread/1044021 and I haven't used that, so not sure about its working